# NBExtension does not validate in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am running Jupyter 4.1.0 on a Mac which I downloaded with Anaconda.

I have tried downloading front-end extensions to Jupyter Notebook but cannot get the packages to validate. For example after I downloaded calico-document-tools with:

```
jupyter nbextension install https://github.com/Calysto/notebook-extensions/archive/master.zip
```

When I try to validate it, I get the following.

```
$ jupyter nbextension enable calico-document-tools
Unrecognized JSON config file version, assuming version 1
Enabling notebook extension calico-document-tools...
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X calico-document-tools
```

What does this error message mean?

Comment: Changing `$ jupyter nbextension enable calico-document-tools` to `$ jupyter nbextension enable calico-document-tools/calico-document-tools` seemed to help, but I am not entirely sure why. Perhaps the enable statement needs to point to a file rather than a folder?

Comment: I think the enable command does need to point to a file - 'enabling' it basically tells the notebook to load that javascript file.